# Jquery ajax() error : "Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: %2Cacpitool%2Caide"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a error when I tried to send post data with `ajax()` method.

I have a array with :

- acpitool
- aide

I use `encodeURIComponent()` for passing the array with data: but the ajax method fail.

Could you help me?
Thanks

Edit :

This is the ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'AjaxSearch.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: param+"="+package,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
    }
});
```

package is a Array like this :

```
var package = new array("acpitool","aide");
```

Sometimes, I have this :

```
var package = new array("bonnie++");
```

For both, I have an error :

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: +

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't forget to visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq and if you can, give code snippets or links to your code so that we can help you better...

Comment: post the actual $.ajax() call you make and we should be able to spot the problem

Comment: I really don't know where to start... `new array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'AjaxSearch.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {
      param:  $.param(package);
   }
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(data) {
   }
});
```

use jQuerys [.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) method to serialize an array.

> Description: Create a serialized representation of an array or object, suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request.

**update**
based on your comment, try this

```
data: {
      param:  package.join(',');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a edit error..

the correct line is :

data: param+"="+package,

Comment: param is the name of the variable like :

?p=var

i test your code,

thanks

Comment: it don't work, because i would like to send package like a string..

This is the result expected :

?p=acpitool,aide

not 
param=&acpitool&aide